# Eiegenvalue equation

Tags: linear-algebra, eigenvalues-eigenvectors

I have a matrix $M = D X X^T$, where $D$ is a diagonal matrix with real entries, and $X$ is a $n \times d$ matrix. Note that $M$ is not symmetric. I want to find the vectors $\alpha$ for which:

$$X^T D X X^T \alpha = \lambda X^T \alpha$$

I think I have the answer but I'm unsure if the following is correct.
Left multiply by $D X X^T$ to obtain:

$$D X X^T D X X^T \alpha = \lambda D X X^T \alpha$$

or:

$$MM \alpha = \lambda M \alpha$$

So now I want to find the vectors $\alpha$ that satisfy this equation.
Can I find these vectors $\alpha$ by solving the following eigenvalue equation?
$$ M \alpha = \lambda \alpha$$

Comment: $M M \alpha = \lambda M \alpha$ means that $(M^2-\lambda M)$ is not invertible. This happens if and only if $M$ is not invertible or $\lambda$ is an eigenvalue of $M$. Does that answer your question?

Comment: I think you are saying that for the third equation in my post, that if this equation is valid, that $\lambda$ is an eigenvalue of $M$. OK, nice. But I want to find the vector $\alpha$, can I then also just use the eigenvectors of $M$?

Comment: Not quite: $\alpha$ is an eigenvector with eigenvalue either $\lambda$ or $0$.

Comment: @Ian's comment is false, as the example $M = \begin{bmatrix} 1 & 1 \\ 0 & 0\end{bmatrix}$ shows, with $a = \begin{bmatrix} 0 \\ 1 \end{bmatrix}$ and $\lambda = 1$.

Comment: Indeed I made a basic mistake...and it doesn't clean up very nicely. Ultimately I suppose all we can say is what JohnHughes's answer says. We get my answer when $M$ is invertible, though.

Comment: Good point. In particular, if $d$ is much larger than $n$ (and the entries of $D$ are nonzero), then $M$'s invertibility is quite likely (assuming the entries of $X$ are chosen in some fairly random fashion).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your third equation can be rewriten 
$$
Mu = \lambda u
$$
where $u = Ma$.

So to find a solution $a$ for that third equation, you need to find vectors $u$ with $Mu = \lambda u$ (easy: those are just the  eigenvectors of $M$), and for each of those, you need to solve

$$u = Ma$$
for $a$. There may, of course, be many values of $a$ for a particular $u$, but this is just a linear system, adn I'll bet you know how to solve that.

In other words: the solutions of your system are precisely the preimages of the eigenvectors of $M$ under the map $x \mapsto Mx$.

Comment: This is overly complicated, and yet less precise than we can be. In general a solution to $M^2x=\lambda Mx$ is either an eigenvector of $M$ with eigenvalue $\lambda$ or an eigenvector of $M$ with eigenvalue $0$.

Comment: @Ian: Consider $M = \begin{bmatrix} 1 & 1 \\ 0 & 0\end{bmatrix}$, for which $e_2$ is not an eigenvector, but does satisfy $M^2 x  = \lambda Mx$ for $\lambda = 1$. The point is that while $(M^2 - \lambda M) x = 0$ factors as $(M - \lambda I) M x = 0$, and zeros of the two factors provide the answers you describe, the first factor may have a zero that's in the IMAGE of the second factor.

Comment: Indeed: one gets the result I said when $M$ is invertible, but not in general.